# How to get expiration notification of an auto-renewable subscription of the In-App Purchase?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I've implemented a purchase of the auto-renewable subscription type in my iOS app, however I can't find a good way to get the expiration notification of the subscription when a user unsubscribed it and the already purchased subscription expires.

One of the method I can think of is to call `[[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions]`
repeatedly, this method will retrieve all completed transactions from iTunes connect and I can figure out if the corresponding subscription has expired or not buy validate its receipt,but the side effect is it will bring up an alert view asking the user for the password of his/her AppStore account,this could be very annoying to users so seems it's not a good idea.

So,my question is...How can I get the expiration notification without disturbing the user?